# WebLogic--->Cannot load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: datasource, weblogic-10.x, mysql-connector

i have a problem in creating a data source in weblogic application server 10.3, i'm making a JDBC connection for MySql database , i placed the mysql driver in the lib folder of weblogic `\wlserver_10.3\server\lib` and in the mysql folder `wlserver_10.3\server\ext\jdbc\mysql` independently and the error message still arises

Note: there was a two jar files in this folder `wlserver_10.3\server\ext\jdbc\mysql` and i removed them to avoid any conflict, how i can solve these problem??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If somebody looks for a solution how to add JDBC driver (in my case PostgreSQL) to a Weblogic 14c installation attached to **IntelliJ IDEA**:

[image]

The location of jar-file doesn't matter. It is not needed to put it into the server's `lib` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using or need a different driver than the one that comes with the weblogic install? If you are you will need to add it to the CLASSPATH in setDomainEnv.sh. Otherwise it will default to using:

```
\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.x.x-bin.jar
```

We had to add additional Oracle jars to our CLASSPATH recently for secure connections. You can check into it more here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/jdbc_admin/third_party_drivers.html